# Inner class in Android R file

Tags: java, android, xml

Is there any way to create an inner class in the auto-generated R file?
Right now R file looks like this:

```
public static final class id {
  public static final int button1=0x7f020000;
  public static final int button2=0x7f020001;
  public static final int text1=0x7f020002;
}
```

And to access it, you should type

```
R.id.button1
```

What do I want to get it something like this:

```
public static final class id {
  public static final class activity1 {
    public static final int button1=0x7f020000;
  }
  public static final int button1=0x7f020001;
}
```

So I can access it with

```
R.id.activity1.button1
```

It is possible to manually edit the file, but that's not the way I'm looking for

**Update:** I need this because my current project consists of around 20 activities, with 5-30 widgets on each of them. I'm skipping a lot of ids(mostly for buttons and layout), but still it's not comfortable to type something like

AcEventListToolbarUserImageView

(AcEventList - name of activity, Toolbar - frame, UserImageView - user picture)

**Update 2:** partial solution is:
in activity layout xml

```
<TextView android:id="@+id_ActivityName/WidgetName" />
```

in the java code it will be:

```
R.id_ActivityName.WidgetName
```

Pros:

see all your activity list after typing "R.id_";

see all widget ids for the activity you need by typing "R.id_ActivityYouNeed."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auto-generation of the R.java file is purely there as a mechanism to allow you to easily reference the contents of your `res` hierarchy from your code. As such, you cannot create sub-hierarchies.

The simple solution is to add context to your item names instead. For example, use `@+id/Activity1_button1`, and you can access this as `R.id.Activity1_button1`.

Comment: Your answer pointed me the way - I'd like to use underscores in the package name, not in the widget name - so there will be several packages named as layouts preceeded with id_.

Comment: I would advise against messing with the package name in this way. In some cases, Android *expects* a fixed package name, and if you go messing with them, you may find that some things just stop working.

Comment: Just for future use - in what cases android expects fixed resource package name(for example, "id" instead of "id_SomeActivity")? I've tried to use id_ method and found it much comfortable than using ActivityName_WidgetName. But if there's possible problem with that, I want to be prepared

Answer (score 1):

The R file is created automaticallly and it SHOULD NOT be edited...even if u try to do that manually when u run ur code a new R file will be created. can u give a reason why you need to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this helps, but you could define your own hierarchical structure of Id containing classes that are defined in terms of your actual resources. You would still need to type the fully qualified name, but only once.

Like this:

```
public static final class MyResources {
    public static final class activity1 {
        public static final int button1=R.id.blahblah_button1;
    }
    public static final int button1=0x7f020001;
}
```

then refer to them as:
    MyResources.activity1.button1;